# install findlib error?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I downloaded findlib from http://download.camlcity.org/download/findlib-1.3.2.tar.gz. After `configure` successfully, `make all` reports:

```
for p in findlib; do ( cd src/$p; make all ); done
"Makefile", line 141: Could not find depend
make: fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
*** Error code 1enter code here
```

I am using FreeBSD 9.0. After `pkg_add -r ocaml`, there is no findlib.

Sincerely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports-bugs/2012-May/233273.html) there is an up-to-date ocaml-findlib port. Have you tried it?

Comment: the ocaml-findlib port works, thanks!  But why cannot i compile the downloaded tar file ?

Comment: Well, for a start I suppose you should rather use `gmake`. For other details, see the patches distributed with the port.